# Install VMware Tools on Ubuntu machine

Tags: command-line, vmware-tools

Trying to install VMWare tools on Ubuntu 10 that is running in VMWare machine. Tools are mounted on `/media/VMware Tools`

I do:

```
sudo sh run_upgrade.sh
```

but got :

```
exec: 1: 10: not found
```

How to solve problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 10??? That's not supported any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always did it this way.  Just copy the file V`MwareTools-xx.x.x-xxxxxxx.tar.gz` to the downloads folder, and the extract it.

Once extracted, you will get a folder called `vmware-tools-distrib`.  The just open that folder in terminal, and just run:

```
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

And that will install VMware Tools

Comment: where does it install this stuff